# Probability that between two Bernoulli sequences, one will get 'ahead' and remain there to sequence end.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

As per title, given two Bernoulli sequences both of length $N$ with probability of success $P$ the same for both, what is the probability that one will 'get ahead' in its sum from 1st of the sequence to the current sequence position (or said another way, one of the two sequences has a first hit that gives them a lead before the other) and then stays ahead through sequence position $N$ (the end).

E.G., if the two sequences were $0,1,0,0,1$ and $1,1,0,1,0$ the latter 'got ahead' at the start, and stayed ahead.

Answers outright, hints, pointers to literature all appreciated, I have hit a wall beyond enumerating and counting simple examples.

I searched other queries here, found nothing similar.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that these are just two discrete random walks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, this is in fact how I did my simulation via Mathematica. I realized pondering it later that the net result is the same as a random 1-D walk of the difference, so the problem becomes one of "what's the probability that the walk with probability p-p^2 of going either +1 or -1, and probability 1-2(p-p^2) of 'staying put', of leaving and never returning to the origin after N steps". That's where I'm at. Background: I'm a retired mechanic, I just enjoy math, so there is probably something obvious I'm unaware of. I'll continue pondering, thanks again for taking the time

Answer (score -1):

This is my attempt to solve the problem and it could be a little different.

Let us assume that the sequence E gets ahead and stays ahead through the sequence. Another

way of interpretation is that its expected number of successes is always greater than that

of  the sequence G. Thus the required probability is Expected Success of E/(Expected

Successes of E+ Expected Successes of G).

Let us assume that E stays ahead after the first two positions of sequence. This can happen

in the following ways when compared to G. Thus E will have successes in the first two

positions. G which is lagging will have (Failure, success),(success, failure),

(failure,failure) and (success, success). The first three will characterize its lag and the

last will put the two positions unchanged with no clear winner of getting ahead.

Thus Expected Successes of E, $$\bar{E} =2*3p^2+(\bar{E}+1)*p$$.

Meaning three subsequent successes and hence $3p^2$  and one position after with a

probability of keeping the success.

Similarly Expected Successes of G,$$\bar{G}= [2.p.(1-p)+(1-p)^2].2+(\bar{G}+1).(1-p)$$ meaning

the probability of (Failure, success),(Success, failure) and (failure, failure) and one

position after with a probability of keeping the failure

$$\bar{E}=3p^2*2+p*\bar{E}+p$$ $$=> \bar{E}(1-p) = 6p^2+p$$  $$=> \bar{E}=\frac{(6p^2+p)}{(1-p)}$$

$$\bar{G}= [2p(1-p)+(1-p)^2]*2 + \bar{G}*(1-p)+ (1-p)$$  $$=>\bar{G}(1-1+p) = (1-p)*(4p+2-2p+1)$$

$$ =>\bar{G} = \frac{((1-p)*(2p+3))}{p}$$

Required Probability $$=\frac{[p^2(6p+1)]}{[(8p^3-4p+3)]}$$

Dynamics of the required probability given p to make sure $0\leq required Prob\leq 1$

0   0

0.1 0.006134969

0.2 0.038869258

0.3 0.125

0.4 0.284518828

0.5 0.5

0.6 0.711340206

0.7 0.86548913

0.8 0.952772074

0.9 0.990825688

1   1

Thanks

Satish

Comment: Thanks for the reply, wanted to acknowledge. It does not seem to contain anything depending on N (the length of each sequence), so I don't think it answers my query but perhaps a hint is there. Will re-read it. Thank you again for taking the time.